# Python3 Download Code

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, web, download

Hi I want to download the linked pdf files from the following url:

https://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+5g/0/1/0/all/0/1?skip=0&query_id=32bdbf71e4007c69

Is there any Python3 code available for this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could read the page with urllib.request, parse it with BeautifulSoup and download all the pdf once again with urllib.request

Comment: Do you have any example?

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Python 3.x
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve

URL = 'https://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+5g/0/1/0/all/0/1?skip=0&query_id=32bdbf71e4007c69'

OUTPUT_DIR = ''  # path to output folder, '.' or '' uses current folder

u = urlopen(URL)
try:
    html = u.read().decode('utf-8')
finally:
    u.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
#print(soup)
for link in soup.select('a[href^="/pdf"]'):
    href = link.get('href')
    href1 = 'https://arxiv.org'+ href + '.pdf'
    #print(href)

    print(href)
    print(href1)

    if not any(href1.endswith(x) for x in ['.pdf']):
        continue

    filename = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, href1.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])

    # We need a https:// URL for this site
    #href = href.replace('http://','https://')
    print(filename)
    print("Downloading %s to %s..." % (href1, filename) )
    urlretrieve(href1, filename)
    print("Done.")
```